# Mongo Query for Multiple conditions with limit and skip

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The document format of all collections in `db` is as :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e0983863bcf0dab51f2872b"
    },
    "word": "never",  // get the `word` value for each of below queries
    "wordset_id": "a42b50e85e",
    "meanings": [{
        "id": "1f1bca9d9f",
        "def": "not ever",
        "speech_part": "adverb",
        "synonyms": ["ne'er"]
    }, {
        "id": "d35f973ed0",
        "def": "not at all",
        "speech_part": "adverb"
    }]
}
```

I am trying to query for word/words,

1) where word `length` is `4` and `speech_part` is `noun` containing  `ac` (%something% in sql) in it (The result would `jack`,......)

2) how to add all three `starting with` , `ending with` , `containing` in single query (eg: starting with `j` , containing `ac` , ending with `k`----> would give `jack`)

I have tried for 1) as:

```
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "meanings.speech_part": "noun",
                "word": "/ac/",
                "$expr": {"$eq": [{"$strLenCP": "$word"}, 4]}
            }
        }

    ]
query=db[collection].aggregate(pipeline)
```

But I got no result for this, also how to add skip and limit for an aggregate , should i use `facet` ?

referring SO answer, i found this:

```
db.Order.aggregate([
    { '$match'    : { "company_id" : ObjectId("54c0...") } },
    { '$sort'     : { 'order_number' : -1 } },
    { '$facet'    : {
        metadata: [ { $count: "total" }, { $addFields: { page: NumberInt(3) } } ],
        data: [ { $skip: 20 }, { $limit: 10 } ] // As shown here------
    } }
] )
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from this code  `"word": "/ac/"` and change it to `"word": /ac/`, and it works.

Comment: @prasad_ How could i check this in compass for results , compass --> aggregation --> ?

Comment: There is a _Select_ aggregation stage drop-down box. Click that, select the stage and add your aggregation code. Then add more stages using the Add Stage button below it.

Comment: I tried exactly the same but, no result turned up mate

Comment: Here are instructions to use [Aggregation in Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/aggregation-pipeline-builder/).

Comment: I have gone through this sir, but actually when i try the query it should give me jack, but no result came

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205489/discussion-between-prasad-and-codenewbie).

Answer (score 0):

For reference `Pythonic` pipeline would look like this:

```
    pipeline = [
            {
                '$match': {
                    "$expr": {"$eq": [{"$strLenCP": "$word"}, 4]},
                    'word': re.compile('ac'),
                    'meanings.speech_part': "noun"
                }
            }
        ]
```